# Не отрабатывает метод onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Всем привет.

В дебагере заметил, что метод onSaveInstanceState() не отрабатывает и значение бандла всегда равняется null в чём может быть проблема? Смотрел официальную доку, у меня сделано также как и там, но доходя до восстановления значений, я вижу, что переменная savedInstanceState=null

Кто может подсказать, в чем проблема? Буду очень благодарен

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putString("EditTextKey", binding.editTextTextPersonName.text.toString())
        outState.putBoolean("SwitchKey", binding.switch1.isChecked)
    }

override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)

        binding.tViewSettings.text = savedInstanceState?.getString("EditTextKey")
        binding.switch1.isChecked = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean("SwitchKey")!!
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793069/android-onsaveinstancestate-not-being-called-from-activity

Comment: @Style-7, хорошо. А как тогда по кнопке "Назад" сохранять значение?